# Help center: search for 'mcve' does not return the mcve help page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, minimal-reproducible-example

**Phase one:** I was misspelling the term as 'MVCE' instead of 'MCVE'. It's part of the story; take a chair and listen.

Something I noticed that struck me as wrong and certainly not cute: I needed the link to the MVCE description in a comment. So I went to the help center and typed 'mvce' into the search box. It returned 0 results. I assumed at this point I was misspelling the acronym.

So I went to Google Search and searched 'stackoverflow mvce' since Google is quite good at telling me what I'm really looking for. The first hit was the proper help center page, thankfully. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Yep, I was misspelling the sucker! It's MCVE, not MVCE. Get off my back, either ordering stems from proper English :)

**Phase two:** I now stand corrected

So I merrily go back to the help center and this time do the correct search.

**Zero results**. See for yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=mcve

TL;DR

Am I wrong to think that a search for 'mcve' should at least return the page that literally is called 'mcve'?

Comment: A search indexer that uses page content to rank results does not produce the same results as an indexer that uses links to page content.  A relatively minor insight that created a company worth $365 billion dollars that is still without much competition.  Not from Elastic either.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry, that blew right over my head :) I get that you're describing Google, I just don't get if I should slap you in the face with my glove or not. And I don't have gloves so its going to be a fish.

Comment: I'm just telling you that they'll ignore your bug report.  If you want to slap somebody then I don't know where you should put your fish.  Try google.

Comment: @HansPassant got it. Actually I wasn't fully expecting anything to be fixed either, just doing my due diligence. And in case you're not a python-enthusiast, being slapped with a fish isn't actually all that bad. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lefP0_ZM-Lw

Comment: Looks like the solution was to put this at the very bottom of the mcve page, in subscript: "You may have been told to include a MCVE by some helpful commentatory, or perhaps even an MVCE if they were rushed; sorry for the initialisms, this is what they were referring to."

Comment: Thanks and apologies both to Shog9 for such a swift resolution; the apologies are for me stating I didn't expect it to be fixed, I will be having those words for supper.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I really would like to have that fixed. But I'll give the search-engine some slack:

[image: not found]

The content of the help center does not contain the word MCVE. The only place where `mcve` is used is in the URL. And based on your and mine observation we have to assume that URLs are not indexed by the search engine on Stack Overflow.

One possible easy fix would be to squeeze the word *MCVE* somewhere into that text so it does get indexed and with that the page should pop-up as a hit when searched for *MCVE*.

For example the trick [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) performed by adding this to the end of that page:

<sup><sup>*You may have been told to include a MCVE by some helpful commentatory, or perhaps even an MVCE if they were rushed; sorry for the initialisms, this is what they were referring to.*</sup></sup>

Comment: Nice one. I actually made a point of not mentioning the search indexing at all even though I was quite tempted to go on the finger pointing tour. The 'bug' part (for lack of a better tag) is only the TL;DR - if you search for MCVE you don't get the MCVE page :) Somebody do something!

Comment: "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (or MCVE)"  Since I believe most (new) users click on a "MCVE" hotlink from a comment, it could be helpful to have them quickly recognize the initialism.

Answer (score 15):

I have had the same problem of finding the "mcve" link in the past.

But there's a simpler way to get the link now. You don't need to search that link anymore.

Just type `[mcve]` in a comment and the link will be embedded automatically and it'll expanded to:

[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

When I type:

[image]

it becomes:

[image]

If you literally see the characters you typed after saving the comment, such as `[mvce]` (without link being embedded automatically), you know you got it wrong :)

---

The search facility, in general, on SO is poor and often doesn't return the right results even if we use the correct keywords. My "workaround" is to use Google. Typically I would search it on google with:

```
my_keywords_here site:stackoverflow.com
```

This will almost always produce better results than the SO search bar.

Comment: Yup, just tried this out, what a handy easter egg. Doesn't work in meta though (lol).

Comment: I know the feature, but that does not change the fact that the help center has a hole for people who are new to the site and actually go looking for what an mcve is. Its not about posting the link, its about finding the page.