# Add "magic link" for XY Problems

Tags: feature-request, magic-links

Comments allow [shortcut magic links](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) such as

- `[help]` - Link to Help Center
- `[ask]`  - Link to How to Ask

and a dozen or so additional ones.

I'd like to see a new one:

- `[xyprob]` - Link to http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/166789

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/166789) is also on Meta. No need for external sites ;-)

Comment: THIS. I have been searching all over Meta. I know they were documented somewhere but I could not  find them O_o

Comment: Isn't [Markdown Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) official enough?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Ironically, that's actually listed as a source by the snazzy URL

Comment: @Sevvlor: Any time you're writing a comment, you can click the "help" link under the "Add Comment" button, then from there, click "Learn more...".

Comment: You learn something new every day... thank you!

Comment: Following the edits to the question, this appears to now be a [meta-tag:feature-request], not [meta-tag:support] (and was probably originally two questions). I've retagged and changed the title to match. Feel free to roll back if this change bothers you, but please also edit the question content to something else if you do.

Comment: I'm in favor of this but does it have to bee that long? Isn't just `[xy]` good enough?

Comment: Is here any update on this feature request?  It seems like something that is wanted.  Should it be re-raised as its own `feature-request` question?

Answer (score 20):

As [Teemu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu) points out, the current shortcuts are listed in the [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

To request a new shortcut, ask a new [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) question, but as [Carpetsmoker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/660921/carpetsmoker) says, [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) would be a good candidate for the target. You will also need to suggest what the generated text for the link should be.

Comment: Agreed -- far better to point to a meta link rather than an outside link especially for new users because it helps them understand that the meta site is where these type of questions/answers will be.

Answer (score 14):

I would say that, if we do that, we should create a help-center page that explains the XY problem. I don't like the idea of making shortcut links to Meta pages. And off-site resources should be completely off the table.

I think we did the same with <strike>MVCE</strike>MCVE.

Comment: We should probably [have a sentence in a teeny-tiny font](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315774/5067311) saying something about the "YX" problem;)