# Add shorthand magic link for XY problem

Tags: feature-request, xy-problem, magic-links

This is a spritual duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318587/add-magic-link-for-xy-problems) question but as:

- I don't think that was originally tagged as a `feature-request`
- the most upvoted answer recommends making a NEW question with that tag (which I couldn't find)
- There is no accepted answer to that question

I thought I would attempt it.  Feel free to dupe-hammer if appropriate.

---

Can we get a "magic link" `[xy]` for the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) canonical meta question?

Comment: I have always been entertained by questions being marked as a duplicate to another question that hasn't been resolved, even if it's resolved by [tag:status-declined] or similar.

Comment: In their defense @K.Dᴀᴠɪs, my original post (before I edited) practically begged to be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I get that... But my point is the "duplicate" was never resolved, and it's just sitting there collecting dust. My issue is that I don't see how a new question should point to an old, unresolved question as a dupe. If the dupe question was declined or by-design, then I can agree with that.

Comment: If you're not one of the current re-open votes, feel free!  Still need 2 more.