# Alias mvce to mcve

Tags: feature-request, magic-links

"Please ask a [*mvce*]".
Let's link that to [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help avoid confusion, especially to new users.

From the *mcve* page:

> You may have been told to include a MCVE by some helpful commentatory,
>   or perhaps **even an MVCE if they were rushed**; sorry for the
>   initialisms, this is what they were referring to.

I doubt that *[mvce]* will be needed for a different magic link any time soon anyways..

Comment: Only 266 occurences: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/607914 not worth it to spend dev-time on.

Comment: @rene, on SO, MSO, or both?

Comment: Only on SO but you can switch the query to MSO if you like.

Comment: I think I did (try to) and if I did it correctly, there were only 8. Oh well.

Comment: Yeah, do notice that the last line on that mcve page was added because before that searching for either *mcve* or *mvce* in the help center did return ZERO results ... as indicated [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313675/help-center-search-for-mcve-does-not-return-the-mcve-help-page)

Answer (score 7):

I haven't seen any evidence that we need this for any reason. The existing `[mcve]` shortcut works just fine, and I've only seen maybe one or two instances of `[mvce]` in comments across SO/SE sites.

The real question is: Why do we need this? "MCVE" is a well-established acronym. Are people misspelling it in droves? Is there a great deal of confusion out there for which this (as opposed to users paying a minimal amount of attention while typing) is *the best* solution? Keep in mind that tweaks like this cost developer time, as well as a small performance penalty on every single comment that is rendered on every SO/SE site.

Comment: I see. I'll (of course) leave the decision to you, while I can only try to help.

Comment: @alldani Well, the decision isn't actually up to me; I'm not one of the developers (I don't work for SO, at all). But the developers are very busy, so they only can add features when there's a real reason, as expressed by the community and supported by evidence that it would be valuable. This isn't a bad idea; it's just lacking in evidentiary support.

Comment: I understand :) | Happy holidays

Comment: @alldani Same to you!

Comment: "Are people misspelling it in droves?" Not really, but there are people who consistently misspell it (though I'm not sure if anyone has bothered pointing it out to them).

Comment: I sometimes misspell it because I can't ever remember which requirement comes first in the name, but it immediately becomes obvious when [mvce] doesn't auto-convert into a link. I then take advantage of the edit grace period to fix my misteak.

Comment: @BoltClock fair enough. I haven't tried a SEDE query on this; I just have almost never seen it in the wild.

Comment: @CodyGray Ditto. I've done this, too. Personally, I think editing is a fine way to address it.

Comment: I can imagine you don't see many mishaps as there are only [266](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/607914) instances of that misspelling on Stack Overflow...

Comment: @EdCottrell: "*Are people misspelling it in droves?*" I am. The acronym is not currently visible on my screen as I type this. And I literally could not tell you which one it is. Because "Minimally Verifiable, Complete Example" is just as legitimate as "Minimally Complete, Verifiable Example". SSCCE was a lot harder to screw up. Granted, as with Cody, I just check to see if it actually turned into a link. But I'd much rather that it be done for me.

Comment: @CodyGray the grace period didn't suffice this time I suppose. :D